# Decode objects with backticks in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

```
import pandas as pd    
sr = pd.Series(["`1", "2", "`3", "4", None, None, None])
```

I have an object series (with len>10000) that is very similar to the one above. I would like to keep the nones, but convert the numbers to integers. I'm not sure how to deal with the numbers that appear to be encoded with a backtick. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
sr = sr.str.replace('`', '').astype('float').astype('Int32')
```

You cannot convert a string to a nullable integer. The workaround is to first convert it to a float. here is the resulting series:

```
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4    <NA>
5    <NA>
6    <NA>
dtype: Int32
```

Comment: This works for my example, but in my real data the numbers are so long that converting to float creates numbers in scientific notation. The workaround to make your code work was to change the global pandas format setting with `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format`. You could alternatively try another method to just change the format locally.